# How to inject a properties in a class with implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

I wanna use the properties to set some swagger docket to spring but I cant get the properties when I implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar and get an error

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   com.github.sofior.swagger.SwaggerAutoConfiguration.<init>()

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SwaggerProperties.class)
public class SwaggerAutoConfiguration implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar {

    private final SwaggerProperties properties;

    public SwaggerAutoConfiguration(SwaggerProperties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerBeanDefinitions(AnnotationMetadata importingClassMetadata, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {

        System.out.println(properties);
        properties.getDockets().forEach((docketName, docketProperties) -> {
            BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(Docket.class);
            builder.addConstructorArgValue(docketProperties.getType());
            builder.addConstructorArgValue(docketProperties.getType());
            registry.registerBeanDefinition(docketName, builder.getRawBeanDefinition());
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: if you want a workaround to solve this issue, i think i can give one in the following answer

Answer (score 2):

I think it is impossible to do this, because spring have two phase

1.**bean registration**

2.**bean initialization and instantiation**

SwaggerProperties can only be used after phase 2 when it is finished to instantiate, but **registerBeanDefinitions** is the phase 1

Comment: so is here have some else method to do this? get the properties and register beans.thank you very much

Comment: see my another answer

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to inject the properties to your class constructor. 
So the configurations should be Autowired in order to work them.

```
@Autowired
public SwaggerAutoConfiguration(SwaggerProperties properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
}
```

This should fix your "properties" is null issue.

Answer (score 0):

the workaround of this question is to read a new properties during registerBeanDefinitions

EnableCustomSwagger

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Import(SwaggerAutoConfiguration.class)
public @interface EnableCustomSwagger {
    String path() default "";
}
```

SwaggerAutoConfiguration

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAttributes;
import org.springframework.core.io.DefaultResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.core.type.AnnotationMetadata;


public class SwaggerAutoConfiguration implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar {
    @Override
    public void registerBeanDefinitions(AnnotationMetadata importingClassMetadata, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        String clsName = EnableCustomSwagger.class.getName();
        AnnotationAttributes attrs = AnnotationAttributes.fromMap(importingClassMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(clsName, false));
        if (!attrs.getString("path").equals("")) {
            String path = attrs.getString("path");
            ResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
            Resource resource = loader.getResource(path);
            // you can get the value from your property files
        }

        //how can I get properties here,the properties is null

//        properties.getDockets().forEach((docketName, docketProperties) -> {
//            BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(Docket.class);
//            builder.addConstructorArgValue(docketProperties.getType());
//            builder.addConstructorArgValue(docketProperties.getType());
//            registry.registerBeanDefinition(docketName, builder.getRawBeanDefinition());
//        });
    }

}
```

Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCustomSwagger(path="classpath:docklet.properties")
public class Application {
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Properties will still be null. I'd like to do the same thing, have bean settings in properties file and then, dynamically, create and register those beans.

Answer (score 0):

Spring 2.x

```
    import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder;
    public class MultipleDataSourceComponentRegistrar implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar, EnvironmentAware {
    
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }


     @Override
    public void registerBeanDefinitions(AnnotationMetadata importingClassMetadata, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        ConfigurationProperties annotationCp = MultipleDataSourceSetProperties.class.getAnnotation(ConfigurationProperties.class);
        MultipleDataSourceSetProperties properties = Binder.get(environment).bind(annotationCp.prefix(), MultipleDataSourceSetProperties.class).get();

    }
```